# Quantitive and computational improvement of the Oseledets multiplicative ergodic theorem for irrational rotation

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Consider irrational rotation $T:S^1\to S^1, T(x) = x + \alpha$ where $\alpha\notin \mathbb{Q}$ (you may assume additional number theoretic properties of $\alpha$, say $\alpha = \sqrt{2}$ is already interesting for me). Assume that we have a very concrete smooth map $g:S^1 \to GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ (it is given by some rather unpleasant but finite formula). I want to understand the behavior of $f(m, x) = g(T^{m-1}x)g(T^{m-2}x)\ldots g(Tx)g(x)$ for big $m$. As far as I know, this is done by the multiplicative ergodic theorem which reads as follows:

There are $k\le n$ real numbers $\lambda_1 > \ldots > \lambda_k$ and for a.e. $x\in S^1$ there are $k$ subspaces $\mathbb{R}^n = V_1(x) \supset V_2(x) \supset \ldots \supset V_k(x)$  such that for $v\in V_l(x) \backslash V_{l+1}(x)$ we have $\frac{\log ||f(m, x)v||}{m}\to \lambda_l$.

I want two things:

1. Some rigorous algorithm to prove that none of $\lambda_l$ is equal to $1$ so that if I will do some finite computation with the function $g$ with enough precision I will prove it;
2. Quantitive and, more important, uniform in $x$ limit from above. Actually, I will be satisfied with the bound of the following form: for $v\in V_l(x)$ we have $$||f(m, x)v|| \le C_\varepsilon (\lambda_l + \varepsilon)^m ||v||,$$
   where $\varepsilon > 0$ is arbitrary small and $C_\varepsilon$ does not depends on $x$.

Note that for $n = 1$ both of these tasks are doable: in that case $\lambda_1 = \int \log |g(x)|dx$ so we just have to calculate this integral with enough precision to deduce 1. For 2. we can subdivide $S^1$ into many small arcs and approximate the integral by the Riemann sum and then say that irrational rotation visits each arc approximately equal number of times (to quantify the first part we need some knowledge about modulus of continuity of $g$ (that is smoothness), while for the second part we need to know that $\alpha$ does not have any good rational approximations though with some abstract $C_\varepsilon$ the bound from 2. is true for any $g\in C(S^1)$ and any $\alpha \notin\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: Have you tried checking out Chapter 6 of Duarte and Klein's book? It deals with Cocycles whose base dynamics are irrational rotations satisfying diophantine approximation, so you should be able to find a partial answer there (sorry, I don't know the book myself, a colleague recommended it after I showed him your question).

Comment: Interesting question. A couple of comments: (1) the MET. actually gives you something stronger than you state- $\mathbb R^n$ may be expressed as a direct sum of subspaces with expansion  rates $\lambda_1$,...,$\lambda_k$. (2) I guess you want none of the $\lambda_i$ to be 0? (although of course you can multiply the generator by a constant, adding a constant to the $\lambda_i$’s.).

Comment: Check [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.3811). You need domination for your questions. This kind of cocycle is called "quasi periodic cocycle". As @DanRust mentioned, Duarte and Klein's book explain it.

Comment: @RR thanks, I'll take a look into this!

Comment: Property (2) is true for $\ell=1$, as a consequence of Theorem 1 of [this old paper by Furman](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~furman/preprints/uniq.pdf), or as a consequence of the more general Theorem A.3 of [this paper by Morris](http://personal.maths.surrey.ac.uk/st/I.Morris/SAEO-JSR21.pdf). More generally, property (2) holds for any value of $\ell$ such that $V_\ell$ is a continuous subbundle (e.g. the dominated subbundle of a dominated splitting): just restrict the cocycle to this subbundle and use Morris' theorem.

Comment: Part (1) is extremely delicate: you may check [this paper by Wang and You](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.0580) to have an idea of the difficulties that are involved...

Comment: @JairoBochi papers of Morris and Furman looks interesting, thanks but I unfortunately has no idea how to prove continuity of the subbundle since I do not know how to calculate anything about it.

Comment: @JairoBochi part about lack of continuity looks even more disappointing. But actually in my problem setup is a bit different then what I wrote in my post: my function $g$ is analytic on $[0, 1]$ but $g(0)$ and $g(1)$ may be not equal. May be something like what I want can be proved in analytic category or even in my setting with potential discontinuity? There are some things about analyticity in the papers which Dan and R R suggested but I'm still reading through them.

Comment: Hmm, your situation seems complicated. Do your matrices have positive entries? This could help a lot.

Comment: @JairoBochi : I have a question about your last comment. What you wanna get by positive entries? Hyperbolicity? As far as i know matrices have positive entries implies hyperbolicity in 2D.  It does not work for higher dimention( Do you know contour example?).

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov I know some papers by Backes who proved continuity of the subbundle for periodic point. It might help you.

Comment: @JairoBochi even worse, my coefficients are in general complex (though we of course can reduce $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ to $GL(2n, \mathbb{R})$, but then we will definitely have negative coefficients).

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov You can use topological presuree that is analytic.

Comment: @r-r If the matrices are entrywise positive then the bundle $V_1$ is one-dimensional and dominating (in particular continuous).

Comment: @Jairo Bochi. Could you please introduce a reference for it?

Comment: @RR Unfortunately there exists no comprehensive reference on dominated splittings. The [ICTP lecture notes by Crovisier and Potrie](http://www.cmat.edu.uy/~rpotrie/documentos/pdfs/Crovisier-Potrie-PH.pdf) is a good start. There are two caveats about it: (1) it's written for the derivative cocycle of a diffeomorphism (and not general linear cocycles); (2) the cones in the cone criterion are "ice-cream cones" (and so we can't apply it directly to the positive orthant in order to say something about positive matrices). Nevertheless the arguments extend to the more general situations.

Comment: Here is a sketch on how to show that if the matrices are entrywise positive then there is a continuous invariant 1-dimensional subbundle (without appealing to general facts about domination): Consider any continuous field of lines $L(x)$ contained in the positive orthant, where $x$ is in the circle. Now let $L'_x$ be the new field of lines obtained by applying the dynamics (a la graph transform): $L'(x) := g(T^{-1}x) L(T^{-1} x)$. The transform $L \mapsto L'$ is a contraction with respect to the Hilbert projective metric. So it has a fixed point, which is the desired subbundle.

Comment: @Jairo Bochi. Thanks. I'll check it out.